# Optimizer with train_on_batch?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

Is there any point of using an optimizer like adam if I only use `train_on_batch()`?

I do the training in a loop manually (for adversarial training) but I want the learning rate to be automatically adjusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you only use train_on_batch the same optimizer instance will be reused in tensorflow, so the stats should be correctly tracked.

Comment: So on every call of train_on_batch the compiled model remembers it's previous update and optimizes accordingly?